# How can I reference a template within a template?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am very new to meteorjs and to web development in general.

I have 2 templates, and one is housed inside another. Is it possible to get the instance of the one inside a template so I can perform some jquery actions in it?

```
<template name="customTemplate">
  <div>
    <button class="start">StartUpload</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

.....

```
<template name="postItem">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>POST!!!!</h1>

    {{>  customTemplate }}

    <button class="buttonPost">Post new item</button>
  </div>
</template>

Template.postItem.events({
  "click .buttonPost": function(e, template) {
      // I'd like to get the instance of customTemplate here so I can
      // manually click the "start" button
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use template instance:

This is an example:

> HTML:

```
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button class="sayHello">Click Me</button>
  {{> sayGoodbye}}
</template>

<template name="sayGoodbye">
<button class="goodbye">
        Goodbye
</button>
</template>
```

> JS

```
 Template.sayGoodbye.events({
    "click .goodbye":function(evetnt){
      console.log("sayGoodbye is clicked");
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    "click .sayHello":function(event){
      Template.instance("sayGoodbye").$(".goodbye").click();      
    }
  });
```

This was a general example. In your occassion:

```
Template.postItem.events({
  "click .buttonPost": function(e, template) {
      // I'd like to get the instance of customTemplate here so I can
      // manually click the "start" button
      Template.instance("customTemplate").$(".start").click();
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't want to click the "start" button from customTemplate directly. I want to click "buttonPost" from postItem and then simulate a click to the "start" button.

Comment: I am editing my answer in order to make it more relevant. Just use Template.instance

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!